# 3d graphics with python

Tags: python, 3d, graphic-design

I am going to design my first 'real' program (I do have Python and Matlab experience, but have never designed a tool), but have been struggling with which software is best to use to visualize the problem in a nice way.

Basically, I want to make a sort of sector plan / layout placement design tool, where a user can drag and drop a couple of modules into a (preferably) 3d canvas, after which a pathfinding algorithm draws lines between the ingoing and outgoing ports of these modules. These modules should be editable by clicking on them.

I have no trouble with the technical (background) content (making a 3d grid, a* pathfinding, etc). However, I have no experience with displaying such a problem graphically, and GUI design. I have been trying to make this tool in python tkinter, but this feels like a very unconventional and inconvenient method.

1. Are there any 'easy-to-use' options for 3D visualization using python?
2. Or should I consider using an other programming language?
3. Or should I consider using an engine such as Unity3d?

Regards,

Comment: PyOpenGL? http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/